# Css id used two times

Tags: html, css

I heard that css `id` can be used for only one element in a page But this is true when we play with script but on presentation alone this is not affecting anything.

[presentation](http://jsfiddle.net/hjpMs/) Here there is no effect we are able to create things simply(created two div with same id->no effect).

[presentation with script activity](http://jsfiddle.net/hjpMs/2/) Here we cannot do anything this is what we know as it can be used only one time.

**I know without script we are not going to do anything** but i just want to share this things and get other web geeks opinion on this things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CSS selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors):

> What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can have the same value in a conformant document, regardless of the type of the elements that carry them; whatever the document language, an ID typed attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element.

It does not specify what the UA must do when it encounters such a situation, and as most browsers are very lenient what you propose will most likely be styled correctly. But you will have an invalid document.

Comment: Thanks.so you are saying this will be bad on selector level and invalid document.Apart from that most browser will present the style right?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're asking or telling us.

It's simply bad form and [against spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) to use an `id` twice in the same document, so **don't do it**.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you want to use multiple ID's what you REALLY want to do is use a class instead.